# python unit test not finding another folder module

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, module, modulenotfounderror

I have the following folder structure:

sdn_unit_tests/ 
 this contains two folders, 'classes' and 'tests'.

'classes' contains one file 'validator.py' and a pycache folder.
'tests' contains one file 'test_validator.py'

The code for **validator.py:**

```
class Validator:

    def username_is_valid(self, username):

        if len(username) > 10:
            return False

        if ' ' in username:
            return False

        if username.islower():
            return False

        return True
```

The code for **test_validator.py:**

```
import unittest

from classes.validator import Validator

class TestValidator(unittest.TestCase):
    def  test_it_will_reject_username_if_too_long(self):#has to start with 'test_'
        #Assume
        username = 'InvalidTooLong'
        validator = Validator()

        #Action
        result = validator.username_is_valid(username)

        #Assert
        self.assertFalse(result)
```

**Expected behaviour:**
I expect that running test_validator.py will at least find the module, this is my first unit test so I don't know if it will say OK or false but I still expect it to find the classes.validator

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/sdn_unit_tests/tests/test_validator.py", line 3, in <module>
    from classes.validator import Validator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend running `python -m unittest` from the parent directory. This will start automatic [test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery). But for this to work, you must create an empty `__init__.py` file in your `tests` folder.

Update: as a quick way to run `test_validator.py` itself (e.g. from an IDE), add this to the beginning:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
```

and this to the end:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: hi myrmica, yes that seems to have run the test. For some reason I thought the test should be run from the IDE (vs code). Is it the case that tests are run by unittest from the terminal/console?

Comment: You can run the test module itself too, but you have to somehow solve the problem with sibling directories. (if your working dir is `tests`, the import machinery can't see the `classes` dir)

Comment: Thank you myrmica, the update is also useful, much appreciated.